# Проблемы с hover на картинке

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть картинка `.png`, я повесил на нее `:hover`, но при наведении меняется все кроме картинки, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Код в студию, без него думаю никак)

Comment: Предоставьте код, который бы показывал вашу проблему. Возможно вы неверно проставляете правила. p.s. не нужно кидать весь код, достаточно только кусок, где вы считаете может быть проблема. В вашем случае - css правила, которые повешены на картинку

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в нём отсутствует важная деталь, без которой нельзя дать хороший ответ. Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него код, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/150108)

Answer (score 5):

Сложно догадаться, что вы имеете ввиду и что хотели бы видеть на выходе, но например:

смена изображений по наведению:

```css
img:hover{
  content: url('http://rs1054.pbsrc.com/albums/s499/vadimzbanok/1327.jpg~c200');
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" alt="">
```

или так:

```css
.on {
  display: block;
}

.off {
  display: none;
}

.wrap:hover .on{
  display: none;
}

.wrap:hover .off {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" alt="" class="on">
  <img src="https://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg" alt="" class="off">
</div>
```